# How can I insert multiple rows in the same table by one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have two insert queries like these:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES('NULL',name1)('NULL',name2)
```

Those two `INSERT` queries above, add two separated rows to `mytable`. Well can I do that via single query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES 
(NULL, :name1),
(NULL, :name2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sample example how it works

```
    DECLARE @mytable TABLE 
        (Id varchar(1), name VARCHAR(10))
    ;

    INSERT INTO @mytable (id, name) VALUES (NULL, 'name1'), (NULL, 'name2')
Select * from @mytable
```